# C - time() in time.h updates its value every 128 seconds

Tags: c, linux, time, linux-kernel, ubuntu-18.04

I've wrote a simple code to test the function `time()` from `time.h`:

```
// time-test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    float now = (float)time(NULL);
    fprintf(stdout, "time() returns: %f\n", now);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I run this code, I find that `time()` only 'refreshes' its value every 128 seconds.So my output is like the following

```
user@ubuntu:~/workspace$ gcc -o time-test time-test.c
user@ubuntu:~/workspace$ ./time-test
time() returns: 1585473408.000000
user@ubuntu:~/workspace$ ./time-test
time() returns: 1585473408.000000
user@ubuntu:~/workspace$ ./time-test
time() returns: 1585473408.000000
```

And then a little later,

```
user@ubuntu:~/workspace$ ./time-test
time() returns: 1585473408.000000
user@ubuntu:~/workspace$ ./time-test
time() returns: 1585473536.000000
```

If you check, you can actually see that the values that `time()` returns are multiples of 128 as well. I think it might be the operating system that's doing this on purpose but am not sure.

Is there any way to make the values be updated every 1 second? Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows with VMWare Workstation Pro.

Comment: Suggestion: in the absence of a **very strong** reason to use `float`, never use `float`. "Because my teacher said so" **is not** a very strong reason until you discussed (and dismissed) options other than `float`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS) the `time` function returns the number of seconds since midnight on January 1, 1970.  This number is now well over one billion (and approaching 2 quickly, where a signed 32-bit integer won't be able to handle it, the [Y2k38 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)).

The precision of a single-precision floating point type (which is what `float` is) is just not good enough to handle such large numbers with that high precision or resolution.

Use either a double-precision floating point type (like `double`) or the proper `time_t` integer type.

Comment: Indeed, Linux and most other modern systems use the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) single precision format for `float`, which has a 24 bit significand.  The current value of `time()` needs 31 bits, so you can't represent all values.